# Regular expression to allow range of numbers, or null

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Regular Expression, how can I modify it to also allow null?

`[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}`

I would like it to allow a 5 digit number, a 10 digit number, or null

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by null you mean the empty string, you want:

```
^(?:[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}|)$
```

Comment: You could replace [0-9] with metacharacter \d or \\d ^(?:\\d{5}|\\d{10}|)$

Answer (score 16):

Just append `|null`:

```
[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}|null
```

As you probably know, `|` is the "or" operator, and the string of characters `null` match the word null. Thus it can be read out as `<your previous pattern> or null`.

---

If you want the pattern to match the null-string, the answer is that it's impossible. That is, there is no way you can make, for instance, `Matcher.matches()` return true for a null input string. If that's what you're after, **you could get away with** using the above regexp and matching not on `str` but on `""+str` which would result in `"null"` if `str` actually equals `null`.

Answer (score 5):

```
[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}|null
```

should do it. Depending on how you are using the regex, you might need to anchor it in order to be sure that it will always match the *entire* string and not just a five-digit substring inside an eight-digit string:

```
^(?:[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}|null)$
```

`^` and `$` anchor the regex, `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that contains the alternation.

Edit: If you mean `null`=="empty string", then use

```
^(?:[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10}|)$
```